# gitlab cicd for multiple dotnet target frameworks

Tags: .net, gitlab-ci

I want to build a dotnet application on gitlab CICD pipeline. I am following what has been desribed [here](https://www.elliotdenolf.com/blog/build-net-core-applications-using-gitlab-ci).

But I have a project that I build for multiple dotnet versions:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6;net7</TargetFrameworks>
```

To build I have attempted the following:

```
build-net6:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  script:
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --framework net6
```

But this fails because I have two target frameworks it tries to restores also to the net7 packages and fails with the error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.412/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets
/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current 
.NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use 
a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0. [/builds/my-
project/reflectiontools/Project/Project.csproj]
```

Unfortunately `dotnet restore` does not provide an option to specify a target framework.

How can I restore only for one dedicated target SDK? Only for net6 in this case? If this is not possible how can I achieve a multi target framework build in a cicd pipeline?

Comment: The new dotnet is just a new way to punish developers